# SimpleInjector ActivatorException when resolving COM interop type

Tags: c#, excel, simple-injector

When attempting to resolve a type from my Simple Injector container it is throwing an `ActivatorException` saying that my type is not registered although I am fairly sure that it has been.

ThisAddin.cs

```
 private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     var container = new Container();
     container.RegisterSingleton<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application>(() => this.GetHostItem<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application>(
            typeof(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application), "Application"));
     var application = container.GetInstance<IApplicationAdapter>();
 }
```

In another Assembly, in this case `ExcelInterface`.

ApplicationAdapter.cs

```
internal class ApplicationAdapter : IApplicationAdapter
{
    public Application(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApplication)
    {
    }
}
```

IApplicationAdapter.cs

```
public interface IApplicationAdapter
{
}
```

But when it comes to resolve the `Excel.Application` I get the exception as:

[image]

So trying to debug this I thought that it hadn't actually been registered correctly, but when checking the added registrations in the container I can see that the `Excel.Application` has been added:

[image]

I've also checked and made 100% sure that the two classes are referencing the same `Excel.Application` assembly which they are.

Finally I would have added the `Excel.Application` instance to the container but since this is a `__COMObject` I am unable to register it as an `Excel.Application`.

I'm totally at a loss to why Simple Injector is unable to correctly resolve the interface.

Comment: What further would you like me to post? This is all that I do to handle `Excel.Application`. I don't create it, and all that I'm attempting to do is register it in the container as above.

Comment: You're directly injecting COM objects into your application services? Yuck! That might be a Dependency Inversion Principle violation. The DIP states that your classes should talk to application specific abstractions. This probably means that you create an adapter that wraps the COM object. This prevents you from having to inject the COM object. COM objects such, because you are talking to proxies. Such proxy object can cause SI to see two different types; this might be troubling you.

Comment: Yes it's very yuck. But I'm injecting it so that I don't need to create my `ApplicationAdapter` upfront and then add that to the container. I wouldn't have though by using the overload that takes a `Func<TService>` would be creating the type upfront and would be based on the `Excel.Application` interface which I'm registering as? As I can see that the container does have the `Excel.Application` interface registered.

Comment: Updated with an example that could be compiled. Will require Excel to be installed and the Office Interop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why this happens. I can confirm that an exception occurs when trying to register this as in your example.

With what you're trying to do, I agree with Steven's comment, yuck!! Creating your own, possible multiple, abstractions over the application object should be the way to go.

However what you want is possible with some minor changes. Instead of registering the application object itself, which throws for some strange reason, you could register a `IApplicationProvider` like this:

```
internal interface IApplicationProvider
{
    Excel.Application CurrentApplication { get; }
}

class ApplicationProvider : IApplicationProvider
{
    public ApplicationProvider(Excel.Application application)
    {
        this.CurrentApplication = application;
    }
    // c# 6 syntax
    public Excel.Application CurrentApplication { get; } 
}
```

Which you can register as:

```
var container = new Container();
var app = this.GetInstance<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application>("Application");
var appicationProvider = new ApplicationProvider(app);

container.RegisterSingleton<IApplicationProvider>(appicationProvider);

//Make other registrations....

container.Verify();
```

I made a little helper method for readability:

```
public TInstance GetInstance<TInstance>(string key) where TInstance : class
{
   return this.GetHostItem<TInstance>(typeof (TInstance), key);
}
```

Everywhere you now need the application object you can just inject the `IApplicationProvider` and use like this:

```
class SomeService
{
    private readonly IApplicationProvider applicationProvider;

    public SomeService(IApplicationProvider applicationProvider)
    {
        this.applicationProvider = applicationProvider;
    }

    public int GetWorkbookCount()
    {
        return this.currentApplication.Workbooks.Count;
    }

    // c# 6 syntax
    private Excel.Application currentApplication => 
               this.applicationProvider.CurrentApplication;
}
```

Tested with Office 2016 and this works as expected.

Comment: I hadn't thought of wrapping the object and adding this as I was wrapping it by my `ApplicationAdapter` but this works very well. I was just surprised that the interface was unable to be resolved, this is something I'll have to look into just for my own interest but this is a very good answer.